# JSON parsing with multiple nested levels

Tags: python, json

We have source JSON with multiple nested levels that need to be flattened and then inserted into a relational table.

The problem here is that we have multiple objects being returned with varying nested levels. We are looking to build a generic JSON parser that flattens any JSON and inserts into a table.

For example, Type 1:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": [
        {
            "a1": "i_1",
            "b1": "i_2"
        },
        {
            "a1": "j_1",
            "b1": "j_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Type 2:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "d": [
        {
            "a1": 1,
            "b1": 2,
            "c1": [
                {
                    "a2": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to design a blackbox where I just input the JSON and may be few parameters to flatten it out and then insert into corresponding tables for Type 1 and Type 2 Jsons. Is it possible to handle all possible cases within a python function

This is sample output I need for Type 1 -

```
col a | col b | col c| col d_a1 | col d_b1

1          2      3       i_1        i_2
1          2      3       j_1        j_2
```

Comment: What if the input is `{"a": [{"b": 1}, {"b": 2}], "c": [{"b": 3}, {"b": 4}]}`? Will the resulting table have 4 rows?

Comment: what are possible types of values in input dictionary?

Comment: What, precisely, is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a recursive function.

```
def recursive_object_to_table(json, prefix=''):
    for key in json:
        new_key = prefix + key
        if type(json[key]) is not dict:
            if new_key not in table:
                table[new_key] = []
            table[new_key].append(json[key])
        else:
            recursive_object_to_table(json[key], new_key + '_')
```